# Chef encountered with unable to create a node

Tags: chef-infra

While I am running the "chef-client" of my json file. I am unable to obtain the `client.pem` file. Th chefserver instance is being running in google cloud platform of OS platform "RHEL7". So, could you please help me out? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxzd4.png)

Answer (score 1):

[knife bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html), is a part of the [node bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html) (see step 2):

> The `knife bootstrap` command will install the chef-client executable (if necessary), **generate keys**, and register the node with the Chef server.

the **generate keys** is the generation of `client.pem`, which is used to authenticate the node on the chef-server. thus, it appears that the bootstrap did not complete successfully or some changes were made to the node `client.rb` that reference the `client.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am attaching the image of "client.rb" file. So, please have a look.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89G54.png)